# HVM full virtualization - Setup Bastion Host in Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have created a VPC with public & private subnets using the VPC wizard. I am using Elasticbeanstalk to deploy my application. There are two environments: web & worker tier.

Both environments are load balanced and auto scaling is enabled.

Web tier `ELB`, `NAT` & `bastion host` are in public subnet of VPC.
Web tier `EC2`, Worker Tier `EC2`, and `RDS` are in private subnet of VPC.

All instances can talk to each other, private instances can connect to Internet via NAT and everything works absolutely fine.

I followed this guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo-vpc-bh.html step-by-step and I was able to create a bastion host.

In my case I want to connect to a bastion host and access the EC2 instance in worker tier. So when I do `cd /var/app/current` I want to be able to access my application's files.

Somehow, I randomly managed to do it. I was happy with it so I decided to shut down the instance (bastion host) since I didn't need it at that time. Two hours later, I tried to do it again but it was like my brain was erased and didn't work.

When I `ssh` to the bastion host, I get a blank linux instance, instead of connecting to worker tier EC2.

**Edit:** I figured that I need HVM virtualization so I chose `ami-892fe1fe`. When I ssh to the machine, I am still unable to `$ cd /var/app`.

**Edit:** All private EC2 instances have paravirtual virtualization and their AMI is `ami-2918e35e` (set by elasticbeanstalk).

---

### **tl;dr**

I made many changes in those two hours. I am not sure right now what I did and it worked.

The combinations are way too many, so I will ask a few things:

- Do instances in worker tier require an SSH key?
- If so, does the SSH key needs to be the same as the bastion host? So it will automatically connect to the worker tier EC2 instance.
- Is there a specific AMI I need to use in order to work? I tried with many AMIs such as `ami-892fe1fe`, `ami-2918e35e`.
- What kind of AMI role do I need for the bastion host? EC2 instance in worker tier have `WorkerTier` Role. I tried with `None`, `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` (generated by ElasticBeanstalk), and `WorkerTierRole` but none worked. `WorkerTierRole` is just a special IAM role that allows EC2 to access SQS and CloudWatch metrics.
- Do I need to attach an Elastic IP to bastion host OR use the "Automatically assign a public IP address to your instances" checkbox? Guide says use Elastic IP. I used both none of them worked.

Here are the security groups of my VPC (instead of `bastion host` I named it `ssh`):

```
 Group ID    | Group Name | VPC ID       | Description
 sg-1de43178 | ssh        | vpc-fa22c89f | bastion host
```

**Inbound**: SSH, TCP, 22, 0.0.0.0/0

**Outbound**: SSH, TCP, 22, 10.0.1.0/24

All traffic, All, All, 0.0.0.0/0

---

```
 Group ID    | Group Name | VPC ID       | Description
 sg-2ffa2f4a | worker     | vpc-fa22c89f | VPC Security Group
```

**Inbound**: All traffic, All, All, 0.0.0.0/0

**Outbound**: All traffic, All, All, 0.0.0.0/0

---

```
 Group ID    | Group Name  | VPC ID       | Description
 sg-483ff52d | default     | vpc-fa22c89f | default VPC security group
```

**Inbound**: All traffic, All, All, sg-483ff52d (default)

All traffic, All, All, sg-1de43178 (ssh)

**Outbound**: All traffic, All, All, 0.0.0.0/0

---

```
 Group ID    | Group Name   | VPC ID       | Description
 sg-d23ff5b7 | awseb....... | vpc-fa22c89f | Load Balancer Security Group
```

**Inbound**: HTTP, TCP, 80, 0.0.0.0/0

**Outbound**: HTTP, TCP, 80, 0.0.0.0/0

---

```
 Group ID    | Group Name   | VPC ID       | Description
 sg-db3ff5be | awseb....... | vpc-fa22c89f | VPC Security Group (for web)
```

**Inbound**: HTTP, TCP, 80, sg-d23ff5b7 (awseb-......)

**Outbound**: HTTP, TCP, 80, 0.0.0.0/0

---

Bastion host belongs to security group `ssh`. NAT instance belongs to `default`. Worker instance belongs to sg-2ffa2f4a,sg-483ff52d. Web instance belongs to sg-db3ff5be,sg-483ff52d.

I really don't know what I am missing here. Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

**EDIT**: When I connected to a `blank` bastion host I tried all sorts of commands to connect to my worker instance:
`$ ssh ec2-user@10.0.1.174
$ ssh ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-174.eu-west-1.compute.internal
$ yum install telnet; telnet 10.0.1.174 22`

First two commands gave me a public key error (no surprise here). I am not sure what is the best way to import a public key to a bastion host and how secure that would be.

Third command after typing a character complains about protocol mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a new environment in ElasticBeanstalk in Worker Tier, by choosing to load the worker configuration & pushing the worker app to it, inside the VPC but in public subnet so I could access it via SSH.

That way the instance was able to use the application files I needed while still being able to access the database.

**EDIT:**

It is possible to edit `iptables` and using port forwarding to [connect to a private instance](http://cloudpages.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/ssh-to-an-instance-in-private-subnet/) through NAT.

**Lesson learned:**

Sometimes there are alternative solutions to a problem, we just can't see them because we don't think out of the box right away.